# Generics Warning T has same name as type from other type

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>
{
        Repository<T> _repository = new Repository<T>();
        public T Get<T>(int id)
        {
            return _repository.Get<T>(id);
        }
}
public interface IService<T>
{
        T Get<T>(int id);
}
```

I get the following warning

> Type parameter 'T' has the same name
>   as the type parameter from outer type
>   'Services.IService'

I am not sure what the issue is with this, why does it care if my return type is the same as the type I am telling the class to be. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can leave out the *<T>* in the declaration of Get methods. You are not introducing a new Type Parameter for the Get method which *<T>* says. The fact that you return a *T* is enough.

I think this will work:

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>
{
    Repository<T> _repository = new Repository<T>();
    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return _repository.Get(id);
    }
}
public interface IService<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}
```

You can create a generic method in both generic and non-generic classes.

```
public class Foo
{
    public T Get<T>(int a)
    {
    }
}
```

You could also do this in a generic class, but over a different type.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public S Get<S>(int a)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You'd want this instead:

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>
{
    Repository<T> _repository = new Repository<T>();
    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return _repository.Get<T>(id);
    }
}

public interface IService<T>
{
    T Get(int id);
}
```

Basically in you're code you're trying to define `Get<T>()`. When you put that generic definition, you're saying it's specific to *that method*, not the whole class.